# How can I use a variable as the name parameter in an object?

Tags: javascript, variables, object

How can I use a variable as the **name** parameter in an object?

```
var field = 'profile.email'

var value = 'example@email.com'

var query = { field : value };

console.log(query);
```

**Current output:**

```
{ field : 'example@email.com' }
```

**Output I want to achieve:**

```
{ 'profile.email' : 'example@email.com' }
```

Comment: FWIW, the correct terminology is "property name", not "parameter".

Answer (score 3):

You can e.g. drop the `field` variable inside square brackets.

```js
var field = 'profile.email',
    value = 'example@email.com',
    query = { [field] : value };

    console.log(query);
```